# wrong replace() method capturing group

Tags: javascript, regex

I have text like this

```
Il Piccolo # 22 settembre 2023
Il Piccolo # 21 settembre 2023
Il Piccolo # 22 settembre 2022
Il Piccolo # 21 settembre 2022
```

and I try to group this rows in this format

```
Il Piccolo # settembre 2023
Il Piccolo # settembre 2022
```

I try this javascript regex

```
function groupNewspapers(text) {
  var containsHash = /#\s\d+\s\w+\s\d+/g.test(text);
  if (containsHash) {
    var match = text.match(/^([a-zA-Z\s]+)\s#\s\d+\s(\w+\s\d+)/gm);
    return match.map(function(line) {
      return line.replace(/^([a-zA-Z\s]+)\s#\s\d+\s(\w+\s\d+)/, '$1 # $2').replace(/^\d+\s\w+\s/, '');
    }).join('\n');
  } else {
    return text;
  }
}
```

but I get, instead, this wrong output

```
Il Piccolo # 22 settembre 2023
Il Piccolo # 22 settembre 2022
```

Comment: Do you mean like [this regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/xRMI8A/3)? See [JS demo at rio.run](https://tio.run/##fY@xCsIwFEX3fMWDFppEbW1cxCKdXcQP6NAan6USk5CkVRC/vepoh24XDufAvTVD46XrbFgN23FUGCDgM8Ae6oOCUyelUQYiEAI8hoD3s0MQa7Eh/zifxxNbzNuiLgi59lqGzmhonentER/eNhadp57BiwA4DL3T4FOHVjUSaUZTXkas8ry6LL6b0XJX6ZRXgvGsXSZxHouEkTch0mhvFKbKtHRa/71nrBjHDw)

Comment: is not possible because my data is loaded from database with python

Comment: Can you please update your question with a snippet (press the button that looks like `[<>]`) to show your code running and giving the output? We need to see your code running and giving you that "wrong output" so we can try and provide a fix

Answer (score 1):

I'm not clear on how your code is being run, but I took a guess and just put it all in as a string with line breaks.  It seems to output

```txt
Il Piccolo # settembre 2023
Il Piccolo # settembre 2023
Il Piccolo # settembre 2022
Il Piccolo # settembre 2022
```

Which is closer to what you want, but not exactly. I made no changes at all to your code

```js
const dates = `Il Piccolo # 22 settembre 2023
Il Piccolo # 21 settembre 2023
Il Piccolo # 22 settembre 2022
Il Piccolo # 21 settembre 2022`;

function groupNewspapers(text) {
  var containsHash = /#\s\d+\s\w+\s\d+/g.test(text);
  if (containsHash) {
    var match = text.match(/^([a-zA-Z\s]+)\s#\s\d+\s(\w+\s\d+)/gm);
    return match.map(function(line) {
      return line.replace(/^([a-zA-Z\s]+)\s#\s\d+\s(\w+\s\d+)/, '$1 # $2').replace(/^\d+\s\w+\s/, '');
    }).join('\n');
  } else {
    return text;
  }
}

console.log(groupNewspapers(dates));
```

Comment: Your solution doesn't work for me because you return the same line to me several times. **I'm not clear on how your code is being run** --> look [HERE](https://alexander19.pythonanywhere.com/?badge=quotidiani), press "Raggruppa" button to see the logic of grouping, text with same month+year are grouped into a single row - I use jquery/Javascript, data is loaded by python but you can find `function groupNewspapers` easily in my code

Comment: What I am not clear on is how the code is run. Is it a big string with newlines like I did in my demo here? You have not provided a real demo of your code being used. I had to take a guess here and I was wrong, so please let me know how you intend to call this function with that input.